# jQuery hover animation queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Having some trouble fully understanding how animations in jQuery are queued and initialized.  Trying to get more comfortable with the concept by writing some button effects.

I want to turn the code from the pen below into a smooth animation (as you can see if you hover over the button multiple times you run into some issues) that executes each animation on hover in **ONLY when there is not another animation going on**, and then execute hover out animations ONLY when the hover in animation finishes.

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/larukayi/1/edit

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think below changes give you the expected result:

```
  button1.css("cursor", "pointer").hover(
        function(){
        slideup.stop(true).animate({
          "bottom":"0px"
        }, 150, 'linear');
        slideup.delay(100).animate({
          "left":"50px"
        },150,'linear');
        slideright.delay(550).animate({
          "left":"0px"
        }, 100, 'swing');
      }, 
    function(){
        slideright.stop(true).animate({
          "left":"-50px"
        },150,'linear');
        slideup.delay(100).animate({
          "left":"0px"
        }, 150, 'linear');
        slideup.delay(100).animate({
          "bottom":"-100px"
        },150,'linear');
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, but is there a way to get the animation on hover in to COMPLETE each time its hovered?  What I mean by this is I want the animation to execute fully when I hover over it, regardless of whether or not I hover OUT in the middle of the animation?

Comment: When it will animate back to the original position ?

Comment: I want to go through the entire animation on hover in/hover out.  If I hover over the button once and hover out before the animation for hover IN is done, I still want it to complete and return back to original position before any other animation tries to start.

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/cijovamo/1/edit), hope it suits your goal.. ^^